# Trying to create a view of a node that contains the titles of nodes that reference it

Tags: 7, views

I'm looking for output that looks somewhat like this:

**Node title!**

Node body, this is the body of the "main" node, other nodes reference it!

create comments link, share links, some flag or something...

- Child node 1
- Child node 2
- Child node 3

The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out a way to do this in views that works with how this is going to be displayed.The main wildcard here is that I'm outputting a list of nodes, not a single one. So using something like an attachment wouldn't work, since that gets appended to the end of the entire view's output, rather than to the end of a row's output.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Entity Views Attachment](http://drupal.org/project/eva) module? Sounds like this is a perfect example for this module...

Answer (score 0):

You have to add reverse node relationship with reference field then add node:title in display field which uses this relationship.

Comment: When I do this I don't get a single list of all nodes that reference the parent, I get a separate row (with duplicate parent information) for each child node.

Comment: In your view->Advanced->OTHER->Query settings enable Distinct option.

Comment: If I do this the output doesn't change, if I do this AND enable aggregation then I only get one listing per parent node, but I also only get one child node, not an enumeration of child nodes.